# Need to invert a loop in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintVshape {
   public static void main(String [] args){
       Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
           for(int k=6;k>i;k--){
               System.out.print("x");
           }
           System.out.print("V");
           for(int j=7;j>i;j--){
               System.out.print("p");
           }
           System.out.print("V");
           System.out.print("\n"); 
      }   
   }
}
```

This prints out the following:

```
xxxxxxVpppppppV
xxxxxVppppppV
xxxxVpppppV
xxxVppppV
xxVpppV
```

This is a homework problem. It's the x's that I'm stuck on. I need to invert them so they become more instead of fewer.

Comment: What do you suppose would happen if we incremented the value of `k` instead of decrementing it?

Comment: Can you give expected output as such? What do you mean by inverting?

Answer (score 1):

The loop you have for `x` says that run it from 6 to `i` and `i` moves from 0 to 5;

```
 for(int k=6;k>i;k--){
   System.out.print("x");
   }
```

Which means `x` will be printed 6 times , 5 times .. ..

Correct the loop for `x` and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop on `k` up to some increasing value, such as `i`, or in this case, `i+2`, to get the range between two `x`s in the first row to six `x`s in the last:

```
for (int k = 0; k < i+2; k++) {
    System.out.print("x");
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help. I got it down to almost a V except the very last line is printing an extra V. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

       for(int k=0;k<i+2;k++){
           System.out.print("x");
       }

       System.out.print("V");
       for(int j=7;j>i;j--){
       System.out.print("p");
          }
       System.out.print("V");
       System.out.print("\n"); 
          }   
       }
```

result:

```
xxVpppppppV
xxxVppppppV
xxxxVpppppV
xxxxxVppppV
xxxxxxVpppV
```

i+2 in k cycle, mean how many times it will print x on beginnig (if you want start with xx then i=0+2)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, is this the thing you are after now?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 8;
    printV(N);
}

private static void printV(int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
            System.out.print("x");
        }
        System.out.print("V");
        for (int j = 0; j < (N - i - 1) * 2; ++j) {
            System.out.print("p");
        }
        System.out.print("V");
        for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
            System.out.print("x");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
VppppppppppppppV
xVppppppppppppVx
xxVppppppppppVxx
xxxVppppppppVxxx
xxxxVppppppVxxxx
xxxxxVppppVxxxxx
xxxxxxVppVxxxxxx
xxxxxxxVVxxxxxxx
```